# How to generate a print preview in winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, print-preview

I am trying to generate a print preview from the form in c# Winforms.
Already added PrintPreviewDialog and PrintDocument and some code:

```
using System.Drawing.Printing;

private Bitmap myImage;

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
     e.Graphics.DrawImage(myImage, 0, 0);
}
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
     myImage = new Bitmap(this.Size.Width, this.Size.Height, g);
     Graphics mg = Graphics.FromImage(myImage);
     mg.CopyFromScreen(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y, 0, 0, this.Size);
     printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
}
```

After I click the button I get the Print Preview and this "Document does not contains any pages".
Anyone have any idea why is this happening? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach your `PrintDocument` to the Print Preview Dialog prior to showing the dialog.

In your example, before this line in `Button_Click()`:

```
printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

You need to add (assuming `printDocument1` is the name of your `PrintDocument`):

```
printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
```

Refer to the example given in the documentation for [PrintPreviewDialog (.NET 4.8)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.printpreviewdialog?view=netframework-4.8) and [PrintDocument (.NET 4.8)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument?view=netframework-4.8) for other adjustments that you may need to make to get the preview you want.